# How to make 301 redirect in Gatsby website hosted on Vercel?

Tags: redirect, gatsby, vercel

[image of vercel.json for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQOEv.png)

I am using gatsby js for my website and hosted it on vercel and now I want to do 301 redirect for my website but i don't want to use gatsby-cloud for this. is their any way i can do it using vercel.

This is the documentation https://vercel.com/docs/cli#project/redirects but I am not able to understand it properly as it is saying to create a vercel.json file, can anyone help me understand it better?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you don't need Gatsby Cloud to make redirections, you just need server rules.

In the case of Vercel, according to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/pull/2897) (and pulling a lof of similar threads), Next doesn't support by default Gatsby redirections of out the box so the only reliable approach is using [`createRedirect`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#createRedirect) API. Inside your `createPages` function (if present) add the following:

```
// Generally you create redirects while creating pages.
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createRedirect } = actions
  createRedirect({ fromPath: '/old-url', toPath: '/new-url', isPermanent: true })
  createRedirect({ fromPath: '/url', toPath: '/zn-CH/url', Language: 'zn' })
  createRedirect({ fromPath: '/not_so-pretty_url', toPath: '/pretty/url', statusCode: 200 })
  // Create pages here
}
```

Next will consume redirects created with this action and creating appropriate "now" routes.

Comment: my website is hosted on vercel so will this solution work for me? also the old url is from my previous website and now i want to take the users to new website url's if anyone comes to that old url. So i have kept all the old url's in json file so that i can map it to fromPath and toPath. So i am bit curious that is CreateRedirect API will solve my issue? @ferran

Comment: It should be as long as is the solution proposed by Vercel itself. Try it and give feedback.

Comment: okay let me try this and get back to you with a feedback

Comment: In that case, that kind of navigation should be treated by the server itself, Vercel in this case, but there's nothing you can do in the front-end side (Gatsby) because you need to perform that redirections before reaching the front-end code

Comment: do you have any suggestions how to approach in this case for vercel redirections

Comment: You may try to use some kind of `.htaccess` (set in static folder so it will be placed in the public one) to make your redirections but I'm unsure on how it will behave overall

Comment: Check both `fromPath` and `toPath`, they don't look like a path to me (From the docs, provided in the answer): Any valid URL. **Must start with a forward slash**)